# c# XML Serialization to Object with Multiple Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, nested, deserialization

I am having difficulty serializing the submitted data attribute for the following, particularly the submittedData element which is an array and each submittedData element has an array of fields (only 1 shown per submitteddata in this example). The xsd.exe converter doesn't handle the submittedData part either.

**Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<forms>
<site>https://www.sample.com</site>
<export_date>2017-08-09T12:04:11-04:00</export_date>
<webform name="form A">
  <crmFormId>form_A</crmFormId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <formData>
     <WEBFORMNODESTATUS>Unpublished</WEBFORMNODESTATUS>
     <submittedData>
     <field>
     <crmFieldKey>aEXTERNALID</crmFieldKey>
     <crmFieldValue>1000</crmFieldValue>
     </field>
     </submittedData>
     <submittedData>
     <field>
     <crmFieldKey>bEXTERNALID</crmFieldKey>
     <crmFieldValue>2000</crmFieldValue>
     </field>
     </submittedData>
  </formData>
</webform>
<webform name="form_B">
  <crmFormId>2</crmFormId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <formData>
     <WEBFORMNODESTATUS>Unpublished</WEBFORMNODESTATUS>
     <submittedData>
     <field>
     <crmFieldKey>cEXTERNALID</crmFieldKey>
     <crmFieldValue>1001</crmFieldValue>
     </field>
     </submittedData>
     <submittedData>
     <field>
     <crmFieldKey>dEXTERNALID</crmFieldKey>
     <crmFieldValue>1002</crmFieldValue>
     </field>
     </submittedData>           
  </formData>
</webform>
</forms>
```

Here is the class I am using. Everything is fine until I try to work with the submittedData element.

```
[XmlRoot()]
public class forms
{

    private string siteField;
    private string export_dateField;
    private formsWebform[] webformField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string site
    {
        get
        {
            return this.siteField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.siteField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string export_date
    {
        get
        {
            return this.export_dateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.export_dateField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("webform", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public formsWebform[] webform
    {
        get
        {
            return this.webformField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.webformField = value;
        }
    }


}


[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class formsWebform
{

    private string crmFormIdField;

    private string versionField;

    private formsWebformFormData formDataField;

    private string nameField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string crmFormId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.crmFormIdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.crmFormIdField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string version
    {
        get
        {
            return this.versionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.versionField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("formData", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public formsWebformFormData formData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.formDataField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.formDataField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class formsWebformFormData
{

    private string wEBFORMNODESTATUSField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string WEBFORMNODESTATUS
    {
        get
        {
            return this.wEBFORMNODESTATUSField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.wEBFORMNODESTATUSField = value;
        }
    }


    private List<SubmittedDataFields> submittedDataField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArray("submittedData")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItem("field")]
    public List<SubmittedDataFields> submittedData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.submittedDataField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.submittedDataField = value;
        }
    }



}


public partial class SubmittedDataFields
{
    private formsWebformFormDataSubmittedDataField[] data;

    public formsWebformFormDataSubmittedDataField[] fields
    {
        get{
            return this.data;
        }
        set {
            this.data = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class formsWebformFormDataSubmittedDataField
{

    private string crmFieldKeyField;

    private string crmFieldValueField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string crmFieldKey
    {
        get
        {
            return this.crmFieldKeyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.crmFieldKeyField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string crmFieldValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this.crmFieldValueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.crmFieldValueField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication73
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(forms));
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            forms _forms = (forms)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("forms")]
    public class forms
    {

        private string siteField;
        private string export_dateField;
        private formsWebform[] webformField;

        [XmlElement("site")]
        public string site
        {
            get
            {
                return this.siteField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.siteField = value;
            }
        }

        [XmlElement("export_date")]
        public string export_date
        {
            get
            {
                return this.export_dateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.export_dateField = value;
            }
        }

        [XmlElement("webform")]
        public formsWebform[] webform
        {
            get
            {
                return this.webformField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.webformField = value;
            }
        }


    }


    [XmlRoot("webform")]
    public partial class formsWebform
    {

        private string crmFormIdField;

        private string versionField;

        private formsWebformFormData formDataField;

        private string nameField;

        [XmlElement("crmFormId")]
        public string crmFormId
        {
            get
            {
                return this.crmFormIdField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.crmFormIdField = value;
            }
        }

        [XmlElement("version")]
        public string version
        {
            get
            {
                return this.versionField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.versionField = value;
            }
        }

        [XmlElement("formData")]
        public formsWebformFormData formData
        {
            get
            {
                return this.formDataField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.formDataField = value;
            }
        }

        //[XmlElement("field")]
        //public string name
        //{
        //    get
        //    {
        //        return this.nameField;
        //    }
        //    set
        //    {
        //        this.nameField = value;
        //    }
        //}
    }

    [XmlRoot("formData")]
    public partial class formsWebformFormData
    {

        private string wEBFORMNODESTATUSField;

        [XmlElement("WEBFORMNODESTATUS")]
        public string WEBFORMNODESTATUS
        {
            get
            {
                return this.wEBFORMNODESTATUSField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.wEBFORMNODESTATUSField = value;
            }
        }


        private SubmittedDataFields[] submittedDataField;

        [XmlElement("submittedData")]
        public SubmittedDataFields[] submittedData
        {
            get
            {
                return this.submittedDataField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.submittedDataField = value;
            }
        }



    }

    [XmlRoot("submittedData")]
    public partial class SubmittedDataFields
    {
        private formsWebformFormDataSubmittedDataField[] data;

        [XmlElement("field")]
        public formsWebformFormDataSubmittedDataField[] fields
        {
            get
            {
                return this.data;
            }
            set
            {
                this.data = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("field")]
    public partial class formsWebformFormDataSubmittedDataField
    {

        private string crmFieldKeyField;

        private string crmFieldValueField;

        [XmlElement("submittedData")]
        public string crmFieldKey
        {
            get
            {
                return this.crmFieldKeyField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.crmFieldKeyField = value;
            }
        }

        [XmlElement("crmFieldValue")]
        public string crmFieldValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this.crmFieldValueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.crmFieldValueField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, submittedData is an array or list too. The idea is each form has multiple form completes with multiple fields.  

I made a fix to .. [XmlElement("submittedData")] 
        public string crmFieldKey

Comment: I made a fix to .. [XmlElement("submittedData")] 
        public string crmFieldKey

to  [XmlElement("crmFieldKey")]
        public string crmFieldKey

Comment: Last edit: I changed the submittedData property to an array and everything seems to be working. Thanks for the assistance. Greatly appreciated.

private SubmittedDataFields[] submittedDataField;

        [XmlElement("submittedData")]
        public SubmittedDataFields[] submittedData
        {
            get
            {
                return this.submittedDataField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.submittedDataField = value;
            }
        }